# Target closest Table Row when button inside of TD is clicked jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

So. I have this table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Element1</td>
        <td>Element1</td>
        <td>Element1</td>
        <td><a id="btn" href=#">Accept</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Element2</td>
        <td>Element2</td>
        <td>Element2</td>
        <td><a id="btn" href=#">Accept</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

What I want to do is: Button gets clicked, it gets hidden and the respective `<tr>` gets `border: 1px solid black;`.

I'm kinda new to jQuery and can't figure out how to select the 2nd parent of an element. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: `$(this).closest('tr')` ?  As an aside, your buttons are re-using the same `id` value, which is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

1. your buttons are using the same `id` value. you have to use `class`
2. Also you don't need to use jQuery. please follow this code

```js
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.id');
btns.forEach((btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.target.closest('tr').style.cssText = "border:1px solid black";
    e.target.remove();
  })
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Element1</td>
        <td>Element1</td>
        <td>Element1</td>
        <td><a class="id" href=#">Accept</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Element2</td>
        <td>Element2</td>
        <td>Element2</td>
        <td><a class="id" href=#">Accept</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```